# ASP.NET Core Dependency Injection error - Unable to resolve service for type "Repository" while attempting to activate "Service"

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I'm attempting to create an ASP.NET Core app using a generic repository pattern using Entity Framework along with a service layer. However, whenever I start up my project I get hit with this error:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'GameSource.Data.Repositories.GameRepository' while attempting to activate 'GameSource.Services.GameService'.

Here's a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of the problem:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var services = builder.Services;

services.AddControllers();
services.AddScoped<IGameService, GameService>(); // Can't resolve service?
services.AddScoped<IGameRepository, GameRepository>();

var app = builder.Build();
app.Run();

public class GamesController : Controller
{
    private IGameService gameService;

    public GamesController(IGameService gameService)
    {
        this.gameService = gameService;
    }
}

public class GameService : IGameService
{
    private GameRepository gameRepo;

    public GameService(GameRepository gameRepo)
    {
        this.gameRepo = gameRepo;
    }
}

public class GameRepository : IGameRepository { }
```

As you can see in the startup, I'm trying to inject my service as well as my repository, but it can't resolve the service for the `GameRepository` when trying to activate `GameService`. Am I missing something? Is this the right approach to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `GameService` change it so it uses the `IGameRepository` interface like so:

```
public class GameService : IGameService
{
    private IGameRepository gameRepo;

    public GameService(IGameRepository gameRepo)
    {
        this.gameRepo = gameRepo;
    }
}
```

FYI, `GameRepository` (the implementation) can't be resolved because you've configured the dependency injection to inject the repository when the interface `IGameRepository` is used in the constructor not the concrete implementation.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for spotting it so quickly. Is there also a way to inject my generic BaseRepository so that I do not have to add a new AddScoped for each repository I have?

Comment: You should setup the scoped DI for each type of repository otherwise you won't be able to inject the ones you need. That doesn't mean you can't also set it up for your BaseRepository too should you wish to inject the BaseRepository and not a specific one. Not sure what others would think of this approach but I think if it met the reqs you needed and reduced duplication it would be OK.