# Dependency Injection Error: 'InvalidOperationException': Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I know there are previous questions on this but they are not resolving my issue.
The dependency configuration has been done in the Program.cs class; however I am getting the following when running my app.

I have two entities 'Orders' and 'Items' with a One-to-Many relationship.
My initial issue was the OrderID (Primary key of Orders) not getting displayed in the Items 'Create' view (to associate an Item with an order).

I added the the following code in the **Items/Create view**:

```
// GET: Items/Create
public IActionResult Create()
{
    IEnumerable<Order> orders = _ordersService.GetAllOrders();
    return View(orders);
}
```

Services are configured in the **Program.cs**

```
//Configure Services

builder.Services.AddScoped<IOrdersService, OrdersService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IItemsService, ItemsService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICSVService, CSVService>();
```

**OrdersController**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using OrderEase.Data;
using OrderEase.Data.Services;
using OrderEase.Models;

namespace OrderEase.Controllers
{
    public class ItemsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IItemsService _itemsService;
        private readonly OrdersService _ordersService;

        public ItemsController(IItemsService itemsService, OrdersService ordersService)
        {
            _itemsService = itemsService;
            _ordersService = ordersService;
        }

        // GET: Items
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var items = _itemsService.GetAllItems();
            return View(items);
        }

        // GET: Items/Details/5
        public IActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var item = _itemsService.GetItemByID(id.Value);

            if(item == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(item);
        }

        // GET: Items/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            IEnumerable<Order> orders = _ordersService.GetAllOrders();
            return View(orders);
        }

        // POST: Items/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Create([Bind("ItemID,ItemName,Price,QuantityInStock,OrderID")] Item item)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _itemsService.CreateItem(item);
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(item);
        }

        // GET: Items/Edit/5
        public IActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var item = _itemsService.GetItemByID(id.Value);

            if (item == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(item);
        }

        // POST: Items/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Edit(int id, [Bind("ItemID,ItemName,Price,QuantityInStock,OrderID")] Item item)
        {
            if (id != item.ItemID)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _itemsService.UpdateItem(item);
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!_itemsService.ItemExists(item.ItemID))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(item);
        }

        // GET: Items/Delete/5
        public IActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var item = _itemsService.GetItemByID(id.Value);

            if (item == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(item);
        }

        // POST: Items/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            if (!_itemsService.ItemExists(id))
            {
                return Problem("Entity set 'OrderDbContext.Items'  is null.");
            }
           _itemsService.DeleteItem(id);
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool ItemExists(int id)
        {
          return (_itemsService.ItemExists(id));
        }
    }
}
```

**Items/Create view**:

```
@model OrderEase.Models.Item

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Item</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ItemID" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ItemID" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ItemID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ItemName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ItemName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ItemName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Price" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Price" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Price" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="QuantityInStock" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="QuantityInStock" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="QuantityInStock" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="OrderID" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="OrderID" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.OrderID"></select>
            </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 10px"/>
                </div>
            <div>
                <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-secondary" style="margin-top: 10px">Back to List</a>
            </div>
           
        </form>
    </div>
</div>



@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Please kindly assist. Where did I go wrong.

Comment: In the constructor of ItemsController, change the OrderService to be of type IOrderService instead, try it and see if it works

Comment: kaarimtareek has a point. You're injecting concrete implementation instead of abstraction thus violating the dependency inversion principle. It's most likely a typo though.

Comment: Duplcate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900414/dependency-injection-error-unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-while-attempting and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61433044/asp-net-core-dependency-injection-error-unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-re

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've made a simple typo which is causing your issue:

```
private readonly IItemsService _itemsService;
private readonly OrdersService _ordersService;

public ItemsController(IItemsService itemsService, OrdersService ordersService)
{
    _itemsService = itemsService;
    _ordersService = ordersService;
}
```

should be:

```
private readonly IItemsService _itemsService;
private readonly IOrdersService _ordersService;

public ItemsController(IItemsService itemsService, IOrdersService ordersService)
{
    _itemsService = itemsService;
    _ordersService = ordersService;
}
```

You were mistakenly passing the `OrderService` implementation when you should have been passing the `IOrderService` interface.

Answer (score -1):

This error occurs when the Dependency injection container is unable to find a registered service for a requested type. You need to make sure the required services are registered properly in your applications DI container.

Check if you have configured your service in Startup.cs within the ConfigureServices() method.

For example:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
```

{

```
    // Register your services here
    services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>();
```

}

Comment: The services are configured in the Program.cs class. See code provided above